# Cocos2d-android - CCGLSurfaceView no class def found, but lib is referenced with source code

Tags: android, runtime-error, noclassdeffounderror, cocos2d-android

I am attempting to follow along to this tut: [HERE](http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/) but using a sprite sheet and animating the sprites. The app builds clean, no errors or warnings, but at runtime i get a java.lang.NoClassDefNotFound error on CCGLSurfaceView, even though i have the library in the class path and have even attached the source code. here is a pic of the error and the library in the package explorer in the apps project folder.[image: Eclipse Screenshot]
the error throws on line 26 in the screen. anyone know what might be the culprit? i realize that it is saying the class file isn't in the classpath but when i right click on the library in the package explorer and go Build Path > , i have the option to remove from the build path, so i know it is in there. for some reason I'm pretty stumped right now, so any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Are you using the most current Android SDK Tools/ADT Plugin r17? Since r17 you just need to place the libs in a folder libs in your project root. The class path will automatically populated.

Comment: i am using r17 just updated yesterday, but i didn't know about the libs folder, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok since you updated to revision 17 you should put your libraries in a folder `libs` in the root of your project. The Android build system will do the rest there is no need to manually add the library to the build path.

The change is descibed at the tools.android.com homepage: [Dealing with dependencies in Android projects](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects)

Comment: okay i've removed all references to the  library and removed the files from the project, created a libs folder and imported into that the cocos2d-android.jar file. project builds with no errors and when the activity runs i get the same NoClassDefFoundError on the class CCGLSurfaceView. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's been 1 year, but the answer is to remove the cocos2d android.jar from the Java build path..

In Eclipse, right click your folder-->Properties-->Java Build Path-->Libraries remove cocos2d.jar and after that drag the cocos2d.jar into your libs folder in Eclipse.

Lastly, right click folder-->Android Tools-->Fix Project Properties and run it. It should be ok. Note: After fixing project properties jar files will have a little library images.